# Query time out using NOT EXIST

Tags: c#, sql

i have a query with purpose to find the records in table item_location and not exist in table operation_detail for a specific month of the year

```
SELECT il.item_id, 
       il.SEQUENCE, 
       SUM (il.quantity) AS quantity, 
       i.buy_price,
       i.sell_price, i.item_name, i.unit_measure_id,
       i.is_raw_item AS is_raw
FROM item_location il, item i
WHERE il.quantity <> 0
AND il.item_id = i.item_id
AND il.SEQUENCE = i.SEQUENCE
AND NOT EXISTS (
                 SELECT od.*
                 FROM operation_detail od, operation_header oh, rt_operation o
                 WHERE od.item_id = il.item_id
                 AND od.SEQUENCE = il.SEQUENCE
                 AND od.operation_header_id = oh.operation_header_id
                 AND oh.operation_type_id = o.operation_type_id
                 AND o.operation_stock IN ('I', 'O')
                 AND MONTH (oh.operation_date) = @MONTH
                 AND YEAR (oh.operation_date) = @YEAR)
GROUP BY il.item_id,
         il.SEQUENCE,
         i.buy_price,
         i.sell_price,
         i.item_name,
         i.unit_measure_id,
         i.is_raw_item
```

Note that running this query from `.net` platform using `DataAdapter` give a timeout, running it from SQL take 40s

My main prob is the TimeOut....any suggest

Comment: have any index on operation_detail, operation_header and rt_operation?

Comment: ever had a look at the execution plan?

Comment: what database system you're using?

Comment: It seems likely that it's MSSQL since it's using .NET on the application side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For improving performance don't use non SARGable where clause. Your major mistake do which makes a query non-SARGable is functions directly on a column in the WHERE Clause.This won't use an index.

Look at this example where declare new parameters for query forcing INDEX SEEK operation

```
DECLARE @YEAR int = 1971,
        @MONTH int = 11,
        @StartDate datetime,
        @EndDate datetime
SELECT @StartDate = CAST(CAST(@YEAR AS nvarchar(4)) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(@MONTH AS nvarchar(2)), 2) + '01' AS datetime),
       @EndDate = DATEADD(month, 1, CAST(@YEAR AS nvarchar(4)) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(@MONTH AS nvarchar(2)), 2) + '01')

SELECT
...
WHERE od.item_id = il.item_id
  AND od.SEQUENCE = il.SEQUENCE
  AND od.operation_header_id = oh.operation_header_id
  AND oh.operation_type_id = o.operation_type_id
  AND o.operation_stock IN ('I', 'O')
  AND oh.operation_date >= @StartDate AND oh.operation_date < @EndDate
```

Comment: Guys am using SQL 2008 and my main prob is that I am not understanding why such a query will take this much time for execution, now given month=2 execution time is 1:30 mn

Comment: Do you have index on operation_date column?

Answer (score 2):

The default time-out to run the query is 30 seconds, and if your command takes longer, it will be terminated. I guess you should optimize your query to run faster, but you can also increase the time out for your data adapter:

```
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 120; // Two minutes
```

Comment: -, `ConnectionTimeout` is not the property to be set, rather `CommandTimeout` of the specific command...

Comment: and additionally I would rather write sth like `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2).TotalSeconds` ;) but that's just a matter of taste...

Comment: Thanks dear, this query is inside a loop running 3 times for months 1,2 and 3, setting the CommandTimeout=120 run the query well for the first time, at the second time it gave "Transaction (ProcesssID 87) was deadlock on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun Transaction)

Comment: sorry for editing, otherwise I wouldn't be able to remove my downvote... hope you understand!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I see queries with more than a few grouping columns, I start to think that the query can be rewritten. In general, you should try to group only on key columns, storing the key and aggregated results into a temp table, then join that temp table to get the additional details. For example:

```
insert into
    #tmp
select
    key1, key2, sum(things)
from
    table;
```

Then:

```
select
    table.key1, table.key2,
    tmp.sum_of_all_things,
    table.other_stuff, table.extra_data
from
    #tmp tmp
    join
    table on tmp.key1 = table.key1 and tmp.key2 = table.key2
```

This will avoid all the overhead of having to sort all non-key columns (which is what happens as part of a `group by` operation).

Secondly, since you have a correlated subquery within the `not exists` clause, you should provide an index or indexes on the match predicate (in this case, `item_id` and `sequence`). The way `exists` works, it will return true if the result set contains any rows, *but it will still need to re-execute the inner query for every row of the outer query*. So you will need indexes to make this less torturous.

Since your inner query itself contains 3 joins, I would seriously consider running it separately and storing the results in another temp table.

Comment: How can I provide an index?

Comment: Do you mean create them, or see existing indexes on a table, or something else?

Comment: I mean the way you want me to do it, you suggested to provide indexes, so how can I provide them?

Comment: I see. I simply mean to ensure that there are indexes on those columns in the relevant tables. Create them if they do not exist.